# What hardware profile tool exists for RHEL 5.x similar to `lscfg` or `system_profiler`?

Tags: hardware, rhel5, configuration

I am looking for an equivalent tool or command to dump connected hardware (and optionally software) to a text or XML file for documenting system configuration on RHEL 5.8 specifically.

I am used to `lscfg` on AIX to dump status of all connected hardware. On Mac, I have `system_profiler` which dumps both hardware and software details.

Is there a similar tool to these on Red Hat Enterprise Linux that dumps connected hardware information for inventory and discovery purposes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should be a utility called `dmidecode` in the path, that sounds like it provides what you are looking for. Some details can be found on the RHEL documentation [here](https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/5/html/5.5_Technical_Notes/dmidecode.html).

Comment: This looks highly useful. I'll dig into it - might be the perfect tool.